# Rendering barcodes in HTML with Code 128 font

Tags: html, encoding, fonts, barcode

Is it possible to render correct bar-codes in HTML using the Code 128 font?
The main content of the bar-code is fine in the broswer (firefox) but when I try to add the start code character I just get this character in the browser:

```
Ñ
```

This is ASCII code 209. I'm wondering if it even has a bar representation.
I'm using MVC but this is really just a HTML/CSS problem I think.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite what you asked for, but you can make barcodes using CSS: see http://unixshell.jcomeau.com/src/barcodes/memberships.html. I'm using code39 for this, but most other linear codes can be done the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the client is going to have barcode font installed?

Server side image generation seems to be a better solution.

You may want to try [Barcode.dll](http://www.lesnikowski.com/barcode/) for barcode rendering.

It includes [ASP.NET barcode control](http://www.lesnikowski.com/barcode/tutorial/WebTutorial.aspx) - just drag & drop.

Please note that this is a commercial product I developed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years too late, but looking again at the question, I'm pretty sure you're just not using the right numeric code for your font. there is no single "Code 128 font". while 209 is shown by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128) to be the correct "common" code for `Start B`, in various fonts I found online this is not the case. in [this](http://www.barcoderesource.com/code128_barcodefont.html), `Start B` is 236; and [here](http://www.jtbarton.com/Barcodes/Code128.aspx) it's 204. use the right code for your particular font, and you should get what you want.

a code point not encoded by the barcode font will be rendered by a default font, which is why you're seeting the N tilde character.